# Track only specific branches on existing remote

Tags: git

I've cloned the [sage repository](http://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/refs/), which contains quite a number of branches. Currently, all those branches are tracked: whenever I `git fetch origin`, I get lots of newly created branches. I'd like to avoid this, but don't know how.

I guess I could remove then re-add the `origin` remote, using `git remote add -t master …` to replace the glob by a single specific branch to track. But I am a bit concerned about what that would do to my local branches which really should track origin.

I also see the `fetch` setting of the remote in my `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://trac.sagemath.org/sage.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I could edit that file, but I don't know whether doing so is safe, and I found no command line tool to modify this file in a secure fashion.

I'm not sure if any of the above will get rid of those refs which already exist on my system. If not, I'd like to know whether simply removing the files under `.git/refs/remotes/origin` is enough. Or do I have to go through `git branch -r -D` or similar for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git config -e` will bring up your editor (from `$GIT_EDITOR` or `core.editor` or `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` or the compiled-in default, in that order) on your `.git/config`.  But just editing it directly is fine (at least on Unix-like systems—I have not tried this on Windows).

`git fetch origin` won't create *local* tracking branches for all the remote branches, only the "remote branches" that local branches can track.

Normally, if git creates many such remote branches, people don't seem to care that much.  Remote branches (which are actually local, so the name is misleading: they're local *copies* of ordinary branches seen on the remote) are stored in a separate name-space (`ref/remotes/origin/`, in this case), so they do not interfere with your own local branches; `git branch` without `-a` or `-r` hides them; so if there is just one `origin/master`, or thousands of `origin/whatever`, it's not that big a deal.  However, as `git remote add` allows in initial configuration, or editing the config file (directly, or with `git config -e`, or with various separate `git config` commands), you can indeed change this.

If you eliminate the remote branches, the main effect is that you don't have the local copies to view or track.  This means that, even if "they" make a `zork` branch, if you `git checkout zork` there's no chance that `zork` will match up with `origin/zork` and create a tracking branch.  But at the same time, you won't be able to `git checkout -b zork --track` either, because you won't have brought over `origin/zork`.  (A slight side benefit is that you won't bring over objects needed only for the remote branches you're also not bringing over.  Usually this is pretty trivial though.)

When you run a plain `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` (as opposed to `git fetch origin branch`), the `fetch` command reads the list of refspecs from all the `fetch =` lines under the remote entry.  So:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://trac.sagemath.org/sage.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

is allowed and causes `git fetch origin` to use, as its two refspecs, those two strings.

Fetch does its thing by asking the remote for *all* its refs (`refs/*`, i.e., all heads, tags, notes, and whatever might be over there) and copying into your repo *only*<sup>1</sup> those matched by the left-hand-side refspec parts (the stuff to the left of the colon).  Each matched ref must be rewritten by the right-hand-side, and the result must be just one single refspec.  (So it's invalid if you ask it to convert `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/origin/master` and also to convert `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/origin/their-master`, for instance.)  You can use `*` to match refspec components, including entire trailing parts, so `refs/heads/*` matches all branches—branches being any reference under `refs/heads/`—and the `refs/remotes/origin/*` replaces the `heads` part with `remotes/origin`.

> I'm not sure if any of the above will get rid of those refs which already exist on my system.

If you *don't* use `--prune` (`-p`) with fetch or its equivalents (`git remote update` is equivalent<sup>2</sup> to fetch), a reference that has gone away on the remote is *not* deleted locally.  If you *do* use `-p`, or run an explicit `git remote prune origin`, a reference that has gone away *is* deleted locally.  I'm not sure (have not tested) how this works with explicit, non-`*`-ed refspecs that only bring over a limited subset of branches, but I suspect they are retained, along with all the branches not brought over.  (But you could test this: simply update your config file to bring over only the branches you want, then see if `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch -p origin` deletes the others.)

Refs can appear both in `.git/refs/` and in `.git/packed-refs` (which is also an edit-able text file).  You should be able to delete them with `git branch` or entirely-manually, as you proposed (the latter is often a lot faster and easier).

---

<sup>1</sup>Except that `git fetch` treats tags specially by default.  Those whose SHA-1 matches the SHA-1 of a branch, i.e., of a `refs/heads/*` refspec on the remote, are brought over with the branch.

If you supply `--tags`, fetch adds `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to the refspec.  Since this does not have the `+`, these are not forced-updates; but they act like any other user-supplied refspec, and the resulting tags wind up in your local tag name-space (there is no built-in "remote tag" name-space).

<sup>2</sup>For some reason the code that implements `git fetch -p` is different from the code that implements `git remote update -p`, and in some versions of git, some remote branches can fail to get pruned by `fetch` but are correctly pruned by the `remote` sub-commands, if I remember the release notes item correctly.